# Weird behavior when deploying a Node.js app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a Node.js app on Heroku which uses their standard dynos. When I deploy new code my site remains up, but for a short period of time some code runs twice. I'm assuming it's because what is happening with the dynos to keep the site from having any interruptions. I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening.

Comment: what code runs twice? and what is that code about?

Comment: I guess I should be more specific here. I'm using Botkit https://github.com/howdyai/botkit and it's the code that is receiving messages. It maybe makes sense for me to ask this question there.

Comment: I believe this is related to Heroku preboot. "When you make releases with preboot, you will have two versions of your code running at the same time, overlapping for up to 3 minutes, although only one version will be serving user requests."